# CRTP & copy/move assignment/constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp, copy-assignment

I am trying to implement a move/copy assignment operators and constructors in a base class for the derived classes using CRTP.

```
template <typename Derived>
class base {
public:
    Derived& operator= (const Derived& other) {
        // Copy the base properties:
        this->foo_ = other.foo_;
        // ...
        // Continue as the derived class demands it:
        this->derived().copy(other);
        return this->derived();
    }
    // etc. for copy/move assignment/construction...

private:
    // To act as the derived class:
    Derived& derived () { return *static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
    const Derived& derived () const { return *static_cast<const Derived*>(this); }

protected:
    // Some base properties:
    int foo_;
    // ...
};

class derived: public base<derived> {
    friend base<derived>;

public:
    // Inheriting the constructors and assignment operators:
    using base<derived>::base;
    using base<derived>::operator=;

private:
    void copy (const derived& other) {
        // Copy all the needed derived properties:
        this->bar_ = other.bar_;
        // ...
    }

    // Some derived properties:
    int bar_;
    // ...
};

// To test it:
int main () {
    derived d, t;
    d = t;
}
```

Compiler gives me an error, saying that `derived& derived::operator=(const derived&)` cannot be overwritten with `derived& base<derived>::operator=(const derived&)`. My theory is, that somehow `derived::operator=` gets defined implicitly and then by introducing the `base<derived>::operator=` by the `using` declaration I'm trying to redefine it again maybe? This looks suspiciously similar to errors that come up when accidentally defining a method twice.

I compiled this with GCC and the full log is:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:25:7: error: 'constexpr derived& derived::operator=(const derived&)' cannot be overloaded
 class derived: public base<derived> {
       ^~~~~~~
test.cpp:4:14: error: with 'Derived& base<Derived>::operator=(const Derived&) [with Derived = derived]'
     Derived& operator= (const Derived& other) {
              ^~~~~~~~
```

Is this even possible to accomplish, or do I have to define the operators/constructors in the `derived` class and then delegate their functionality to the `base` class inside the definition?

### Update

OK, maybe after looking at this with a clearer mind, it seems overly complicated. I could just do the following:

```
Derived& base<Derived>::operator= (const base& other) {
    this->foo_ = other.foo_;
    return this->self();
}
```

So the returned type is correct for every derived class and the copy is performed from the base class - only the base properties are copied, which is all I need by default. If I need more, then it's specific to each derived class:

```
// Adding this to the base class - for any derived class to act as the base one:
template <Derived>
base<Derived>& base<Derived>::base () { *return static_cast<base<Derived>*>(this); }

derived& derived::operator= (const derived& other) {
    this->base() = other.base();
    this->bar_ = other.bar_;
}
```

But still, it's an interesting excercise and the question regarding the compiler error remains unanswered.

Comment: It could be easier to do it other way around - instead of calling derived copy from base, call base `=` from derived assignment operator.

Comment: It's not necessary to use CRTP here. Simply define the copy/move operations like normal in the base class and these will be called when the derived object is copied or moved.

Comment: `template <Derived>` is not a valid piece of C++. Try [`template <class Derived>`](https://ideone.com/BdJStn). If it doesn't help please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Sry, that's a typo.

Comment: I used CRTP in these classes for other reasons, and just thought, that I might use CRTP for this as well. My reasoning was, that most of the derived classes don't need any additional copying/moving, so I would just say `using base<...>::base` instead of writing out whole constructor/assignment signature in every derived class (and there's a lot of them, so it just seemed like unnecessary repetition of the same code).

Comment: The copy and paste operation doesn't normally involve any typos. You are supposed to  show a [mcve]. You create it, compile it, make sure the error in question is still there, then copy it and paste it together with the compiler messages. The code as shown [doesn't result in a compilation error](https://ideone.com/IPIDFW). Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: I wrote a new piece of code so that it contains only the parts relevant to the problem. So that's why I didn't just copy/paste it from my original program. I just tested this exact example and the error is still there. I didn't mention that I use GCC, so maybe that's only a GCC-specific problem. I will add that information to the question along with `int main` to make this example complete.

Comment: *I wrote a new piece of code so that it contains only the parts relevant to the problem* — that"s an excellent idea, but you need to verify that the new piece of code still contains the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t usefully declare a “derived `operator=`” with the usual signature in a base class because, even with a *using-declaration*, it is [always hidden by the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator).  (You could use some other signature for one or both of them, but then overload resolution is likely to be …interesting.)

Meanwhile, you’ve found a GCC bug in that it incorrectly concludes that the two operators conflict rather than one hiding the other.

Comment: And as I understand, the only way to prevent the implicit declaration of a copy assignment is to explicitly delete it, which would again "shadow" the base one? So there is just no way to do that.

Comment: @McSim: Well, *any* declaration of a copy assignment operator prevents the implicit declaration, but yes.  You can always go the other way: `template<class T> struct A : T {A& operator=(const A&);}; using Public=A<Implementation>;`.